# Iterating from the end to the beginning of a single-linked list without reversing it

Tags: c, list, recursion

Say I have a single-linked list with words collected from a file from which I want to be able to print such words both from the beginning to the end and from the end to the beginning. The execution of the first option being coded as such:

```
void writeWords(t_list *lp, FILE *fp, int total_num_words) {
    t_list *aux; 
    aux = lp;
    while(aux != NULL){
      writeOneWord((t_word*) getItemList(aux), fp, total_num_words);
      aux = getNextListElement(aux);
    }
}
```

That is, the list is iterated in the normal order, the content of each node being printed by `writeOneWord`.

Now, my doubt is: as I said, I want to be able to iterate through the list from the end to the beginning as well, and this while preserving the list as it is, so *no reversals*. I know that the code should correspond to some sort of recursive implementation, but until now I've been trying to do it to no avail. Could anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: You realize, of course, that while you *can* do this, if you have to it indicates that a singly-linked list was the wrong data structure to have chosen.

Comment: You say you want to preserve the linked list. Is it okay to temporarily modify it? If temporary modification is allowed, this can be done with just a constant memory overhead (unlike recursions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want a recursive function for this.

Have the function call itself, passing in the next item in the list, then print the item **after** you return from the recursive call.  That way, the end of the list gets printed first.

```
void writeWords(t_list *lp, FILE *fp, int total_num_words) {
    if (lp != NULL) {
        writeWords(getNextListElement(lp), fp, total_num_words);
        writeOneWord((t_word*) getItemList(lp), fp, total_num_words);
    }
}
```

Comment: If `total_num_words` is big enough this will crash soon. There is much more space on the heap.

Comment: It works and is more intuitive than I expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a doubly-linked list. But here's a workaround:

```
void writeWordsBackwards(t_list *lp, FILE *fp, int total_num_words) {
    size_t i = 0;
    t_list words[total_num_words];
    for (size_t i = 0; lp && i < total_num_words; i += 1) {
        words[i] = lp;
        lp = getNextListElement(lp);
    }
    while (i >= 0) {
      writeOneWord((t_word*) getItemList(words[i]), fp, total_num_words);
      i -= 1;
    }
}
```

Unlike a recursive approach, this uses less stack space. But it still requires a potentially unbounded amount of stack space; `malloc` is probably preferable to avoid a Stack Overflow.

Comment: You should definitely use the heap for this.

Comment: Well, since this exercise in particular was about learning how to do it recursively, I'll go with dbush's answer instead. However, I did think about that, and it seems that your implementation is functional and useful, so you get an honorable mention. Thanks!